# Delay Drawing of multiple SVG Paths with Javascript's ScrollMagic Library

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, draw

I'm trying to draw an SVG line bracket on scroll using ScrollMagic. The SVG is basically a "sports" bracket, in that it branches into twos at certain nodes. I've create a SVG with multiple paths, with one main path going from top to bottom. And a certain nodes along this path, the bracket splits and that is drawn with another SVG path.

I can get the SVG to draw the paths on scroll, but they ALL start drawing at the trigger start and the ALL end at the trigger end. What I would like to achieve, is to have each path start and end based on their offset from the SVG bounding box. I've been able to calculate all the required percentages... but I just can't rap my head around the math required to translate those to the scroll.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

See example.

```js
/*globals ScrollMagic */
( function () {

 'use strict';

 console.clear();

 var bracket = document.querySelector( '#bracket' );
 var path = document.querySelectorAll( '#bracket path' );

 var height = bracket.clientHeight;

 function drawPaths( progress ) {

  for ( var i = 0; i < path.length; ++i ) {

   var len = path[ i ].getTotalLength();

   path[ i ].style.strokeDashoffset = len - (len * progress);

  }

 }

 // init the paths.
 // set dasharray and dash stroke to equal stroke length
 // find the top offset and set attribute
 for ( var i = 0; i < path.length; ++i ) {

  var len = path[ i ].getTotalLength(),
   top = path[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().top - bracket.getBoundingClientRect().top,
   perc = top / height,
   perc2 = (top + len)  / height;

  path[ i ].style.strokeDasharray = len;
  path[ i ].style.strokeDashoffset = len;

  // the percentage when this path should start
  path[ i ].setAttribute( 'data-percentage', perc );

  // the percentage when this path should end
  path[ i ].setAttribute( 'data-percentage2', perc2 );
 }

 // init controller
 var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

 // build scene
 new ScrollMagic.Scene( {
  triggerElement: '#trigger',
  duration: 200
 } ).addTo( controller ).addIndicators().on( 'progress', function ( e ) {
  drawPaths( e.progress );
 } );


} )();
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

#bracket {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vh;
  width: 90vh;
  height: 90vh;
}

#bracket path {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>

<svg id="bracket" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 383 758" version="1.1">
<path class="path1" d="M53,0.001l0,218.906l253,0l0,92.705l-74.281,0l0,168.924l32.918,0l0,102.4l-24.637,0l0,174.581" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path class="path2" d="M53,218.907l0,180.029l55.771,0l0,166l-25.771,0l0,124.585" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path class="path3" d="M306,311.612l76.037,0l0,113.502" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path class="path4" d="M53,398.936l-52.327,0l0,103.585" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path class="path5" d="M231.719,480.536l-33.578,0l0,79.44" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path class="path6" d="M108.771,564.936l18.056,0l0,45.975" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path class="path7" d="M264.637,582.936l19.356,0l0,47.098" style="fill:none;stroke:#050e40;stroke-width:1px;"/>
</svg>
```